# What is this HTC notification icon that looks like a pin?

Tags: notification-icons

What is the icon in between the two red lines on the notification bar? I can't find it in the Android 2.3 user guide!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is by places, the application. Just try closing the application and then trying.